# Confused about `is` operator with strings

Tags: python, string

The `is` operator compares the memory addresses of two objects, and returns `True` if they're the same. Why, then, does it not work reliably with strings?
**Code #1**

```
>>> a = "poi"
>>> b = "poi"
>>> a is b
True
```

**Code #2**

```
>>> ktr = "today is a fine day"
>>> ptr = "today is a fine day"
>>> ktr is ptr
False
```

I have created two strings whose content is the same but they are living on different memory addresses. Why is the output of the `is` operator not consistent?

Comment: In practice you will likely never use `is` unless you are doing something fairly complicated.  You probably want `==` for most equality comparisons.

Comment: @dkamins: Well, the recommended way for testing for `None` uses 'is': `some_var is None` (because there's _always_ only a single instance of `None`). I'd say that's a pretty common case.

Comment: @voithos True - I use that (and `is not None`) all the time and didn't even think of it!  But aside from that...

Comment: @dkamins It's also commonly used for `True` and `False`, as they're also singletons.

Comment: @voithos Indeed, however I rarely find myself using those idioms.  `if something` or `if not something` usually reads clearer to me than `if something is True` or `if something is False`.

Comment: @dkamins: Agreed. I can't think of a common use-case for `x is True/False`. `x is None`, on the other hand, is quite useful when you want to _make sure_ that it is indeed None and not some other falsey value (e.g. to see if a default argument was set or not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it has to do with [string interning.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) In essence, the idea is to store only a single copy of each distinct string, to increase performance on some operations.

Basically, the reason why `a is b` works is because (as you may have guessed) there is a single immutable string that is referenced by Python in both cases. When a string is large (and some other factors that I don't understand, most likely), this isn't done, which is why your second example returns False.

EDIT: And in fact, the odd behavior seems to be a side-effect of the interactive environment. If you take your same code and place it into a Python script, both `a is b` and `ktr is ptr` return True.

```
a="poi"
b="poi"
print a is b  # Prints 'True'

ktr = "today is a fine day"
ptr = "today is a fine day"
print ktr is ptr  # Prints 'True'
```

This makes sense, since it'd be easy for Python to parse a source file and look for duplicate string literals within it. If you create the strings dynamically, then it behaves differently even in a script.

```
a="p" + "oi"
b="po" + "i"
print a is b  # Oddly enough, prints 'True'

ktr = "today is" + " a fine day"
ptr = "today is a f" + "ine day"
print ktr is ptr  # Prints 'False'
```

As for why `a is b` still results in True, perhaps the allocated string is small enough to warrant a quick search through the interned collection, whereas the other one is not?

Comment: Regarding `a = "p" + "oi"; b = "po" + "i"`, the compiler optimizes the simple string concatenation by storing two references to `"poi"` in the code object, which are interned in place. `"today is a fine day"` isn't interned because it contains spaces (i.e. non-name characters).

Answer (score 3):

`is` is identity testing. It will work on <s>smaller</s> some strings(because of cache) but not on <s>bigger</s> other strings. Since str is NOT a ptr. [thanks erykson]

See this code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def fun():
...   str = 'today is a fine day'
...   ptr = 'today is a fine day'
...   return (str is ptr)
...
>>> dis.dis(fun)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('today is a fine day')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (str)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('today is a fine day')
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (ptr)

  4          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (str)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (ptr)
             18 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             21 RETURN_VALUE

>>> id(str)
26652288
>>> id(ptr)
27604736
#hence this comparison returns false: ptr is str
```

Notice the IDs of `str` and `ptr` are different.

BUT:

```
>>> x = "poi"
>>> y = "poi"
>>> id(x)
26650592
>>> id(y)
26650592
#hence this comparison returns true : x is y
```

IDs of x and y are the same. Hence `is` operator works on "ids" and not on "equalities"

See the below link for a discussion on when and why python will allocate a different memory location for identical strings(read the question as well).

[When does python allocate new memory for identical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings)

Also `sys.intern` on python3.x and `intern` on python2.x should help you allocate the strings in the same memory location, regardless of the size of the string.

Comment: how small a string can be for that matter/

Comment: You can have an empty string `""`. This is not the whole story though, because two strings can be set to the same value, so that `is` returns `true`, and then you can modify one and undo the modification and the result won't be `true` any more.

Comment: @MatthewAdams You can't modify a `str`ing, they are immutable. You can only point a name at a new string object.

Comment: You can certainly have larger strings than this interned. While you're right that the short string is and the larger string isn't, "it works with shorter strings" isn't the whole answer.

Comment: @agf yes certainly, **sys.intern**

Comment: It has nothing to do with the size of the string. If a string constant (not from an expression) is all "name characters", it will be interned when the code object is created. Plus implementation strings used for variable names, attributes, etc.

Comment: See [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/codeobject.c#l66) and [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/codeobject.c#l4) in codeobject.c (2.7.3 source).

Comment: @agf Good to know. That would explain why "modifying" a string and then "undoing" that would make the objects different. Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`is` is *not* the same as `==`.

Basically, `is` checks if the two objects are the same, while `==` compares the values of those objects (strings, like everything in python, are objects).

So you should use `is` when you really know what objects you're looking at (ie. you've made the objects, or are comparing with `None` as the question comments point out), and you want to know if two variables are referencing the *exact same object* in memory.

In your examples, however, you're looking at `str` objects that python is handling behind the scenes, so without diving deep into how python works, you don't really know what to expect. You would have the same problem with `int`s or `float`s. Other answers do a good job of explaining the "behind the scenes" stuff (string interning), but you mostly shouldn't have to worry about it in day-to-day programming.

Comment: So why are the two examples different? This doesn't explain.

Comment: @agf just edited- Does that explain what I meant my answer to be better?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a CPython specific optimization.  If you want your code to be portable, you should avoid it.  For example, in PyPy

```
>>>> a = "hi"
>>>> b = "hi"
>>>> a is b
False
```

It's also worth pointing out that a similar thing happens for small integers

```
>>> a = 12
>>> b = 12
>>> a is b
True
```

which again you should not rely on, because other implementations might not include this optimization.