# Compound boolean logic in python if

Tags: python

I am trying to test a basic premise in python and it always fails and I can't figure out why.

My sys.argv looks like this:

```
['test.py', 'test']
```

And my code looks like this:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] is 'test':
    print 'Test mode'
```

But the test is never true. I am sure that I am missing something really simple here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: try `sys.argv[1] = 'test'`. I can't articulate why this might work, but give it a try anyways

Comment: I would suggest printing out the values of `len(sys.argv)`, `sys.argv[1]`, and `sys.argv[1] is test`.  That should help you narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: Have you tried `sys.argv[1] == 'test'`, rather than `is`? (edit: ack, beaten to it)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Beat me to the punch :)

Comment: Wouldn't the immutability of strings be the counterargument to that though? I can't justify how that would work

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Does the edit make logical sense to you? I think I feel comfortable with it now after the Martelli/Skeet thread, but can always use some sense-checking :)

Comment: The `is` operator is the identity operatory. You can translate that as saying "is this the very same object as ...".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned above, the main reason is your `test` comparison. Using `is` is different than using `==` as it compares if two *objects* are equal. In this case, you can verify that they are not equal by checking their ids:

```
import sys

print id(sys.argv[1])
print id('test')
```

My output:

```
140335994263232
140335994263424
```

As they point to different objects, they will not be equal when using `is` (but using `==` will compare the strings themselves, which will return `True`).

The issue at work here is the concept of interning. When you hardcode two identical strings into your source, the strings are interned and the two will share an object ID (this explains @SamMussmann's very valid point below). But when you pass a string in via `argv`, a new object is created, thereby making the comparison to an identical hardcoded string in your code return `False`. The best explanation I have found so far is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings), where both Alex Martelli and Jon Skeet (two very reputable sources) explain interning and when strings are interned. From these explanations, it does seem that since the data from `argv` is external to the program, the values aren't interned, and therefore have different object IDs than if they were both literals in the source.

One additional point of interest (unrelated to the issue at hand but pertinent to the `is` discussion) is the caching that is done with numbers. The numbers from -5 to 256 are cached, meaning that `is` comparisons with equal numbers in that range will be True, regardless of how they are calculated:

```
In [1]: 256 is 255 + 1
Out[1]: True

In [2]: 257 is 256 + 1
Out[2]: False

In [3]: -5 is -4 - 1
Out[3]: True

In [4]: -6 is -5 - 1
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: There's something funny about `sys.argv` here, because if I put `'test'` in a regular list, then `a[0] is 'test'` is true...

Comment: @SamMussmann: Thank you (I have the same question). I think what might be happening is that the python interpreter gets its own sandbox to play with, which might explain this behavior -- objects in `sys.argv` are created before the invocation of the python interpreter and therefore live in a memory space outside this sandbox. <-- I have no idea if that's correct. Could someone confirm/deny please?

Comment: @SamMussmann That's because in your test you used string literals, that are interned. Python put the same interned string in the list, so they are in fact the same object. So the test Passes. But that is not the proper use of the `is` operator. Use `==` when you want to compare equality.

Comment: @SamMussmann inpectorG4dget Does the above edit make logical sense to you guys? I want to find better docs on it as I'm not 100% sure, but I think it matches the behavior we are seeing.

Comment: Yep!  And appending `test` to `sys.argv` does *not* give it a different id -- that was a user error...

Comment: @SamMussmann Haha, alright cool, one less edge case to investigate :)

Comment: Cool!  Also, if you call `id(intern(sys.argv[1]))`, you'll get a value that's the same as `id('test')`

Comment: The edit makes sense; and those are excellent references. I traced it back a ways, and it seems to be applicable here.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Awesome, thanks for confirming (I trust your opinion a lot as well :) ).