# Python: id() behavior in the Interpreter

Tags: python

I came across this weird behaviour which happens only in an interactive Python session, but not when I write a script and execute it.

String is an immutable data type in Python, hence:

```
>>> s2='string'
>>> s1='string'
>>> s1 is s2
True
```

Now, the weird part:

```
>>> s1='a string'
>>> s2='a string'
>>> s1 is s2
False
```

I have seen that having a whitespace in the string causes this behaviour. If I put this in a script and run it, the result is True in both cases.

Would anyone have a clue about this? Thanks.

EDIT:

Okay, the above question and answers give some ideas. Now here is another experiment:

```
>>> s2='astringbstring'
>>> s1='astringbstring'
>>> s1 is s2
True
```

In this case the strings are definitely longer than `'a string'`, but are still having the same identifiers.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings

Comment: Be aware that the interning rules can vary across Python implementations and versions. Apart from the idiomatic `is [not] None` case, use of `is` is extremely rare in Python; you should only use it when you really are concerned with object identity rather than value equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Many thanks to @eryksun for the corrections!**

This is because of a mechanism call [`interning`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) in Python:

> Enter string in the table of “interned” strings and return the
>   interned string – which is string itself or a copy. Interning strings
>   is useful to gain a little performance on dictionary lookup – if the
>   keys in a dictionary are interned, and the lookup key is interned, the
>   key comparisons (after hashing) can be done by a pointer compare
>   instead of a string compare. Normally, the names used in Python
>   programs are automatically interned, and the dictionaries used to hold
>   module, class or instance attributes have interned keys.
>
> Changed in version 2.3: Interned strings are not immortal (like they
>   used to be in Python 2.2 and before); you must keep a reference to the
>   return value of intern() around to benefit from it.

*CPython* will automatically intern <strike>short</strike> certain strings (1 letter strings, keywords, strings without spaces that have been assigned) to increase lookup speed and comparison speed: eg., `'dog' is 'dog'` will be a pointer comparison instead of a full string comparison. However, automatic interning for all (longer) strings requires a lot more memory which is not always feasible, and thus they may not share the same identity which makes the results of `id()` different, for eg.,:

```
# different id when not assigned
In [146]: id('dog')
Out[146]: 4380547672

In [147]: id('dog')
Out[147]: 4380547552

# if assigned, the strings will be interned (though depends on implementation)
In [148]: a = 'dog'

In [149]: b = 'dog'

In [150]: id(a)
Out[150]: 4380547352

In [151]: id(b)
Out[151]: 4380547352

In [152]: a is b
Out[152]: True
```

For integers, at least on my machine, CPython will automatically intern up to 256 automatically:

```
In [18]: id(256)
Out[18]: 140511109257408

In [19]: id(256)
Out[19]: 140511109257408

In [20]: id(257)
Out[20]: 140511112156576

In [21]: id(257)
Out[21]: 140511110188504
```

---

**UPDATE thanks to @eryksun**: in this case the string `'a string'` is not interned because [CPython only interns strings without spaces](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/codeobject.c#l71), not because of the length as I instantly assumed: for eg., ASCII letters, digits, and underscore.

For more details, you can also refer to [Alex Martelli's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124011/853611).

Comment: @Amit: It's the space character in the string. A CPython code object will only intern strings constants that are all "name characters" (ASCII letters, digits, and underscore). See CPython 2.7.3 [codeobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/codeobject.c#l71).

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the addition, I totally forgot spaces are not interned.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks very much. That was the missing piece indeed.

Comment: @KayZhu Can you please modify your answer considering eryksun's inputs, so that I can accept your answer? I cannot accept it in its present form, since you talk about "short" and "long" strings which is not the case.

Comment: @KayZhu: Your updated example is related to the peephole optimizer. See the function `fold_binops_on_constants` in [peephole.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/peephole.c#l177). There the limit is 20, so `('X'*21 is 'X'*21) == False`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks a lot of the info! I didn't know about peephole optimizer, definitely learned something :) I've updated my answer with a better example.

Comment: @KayZhu: Just to clarify, it's not the shortness of `'abc'` that counts. Interned strings in CPython are not immortal. Try `'zzz'` for example, and look at the reference counts. abc is the [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc) module.

Comment: @eryksun You really should have been the one answering this questions :) Turned out my understanding that interning will vary between long and short strings was not accurate -- the only thing I could find that related to string length is [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0e41c4466d58/Objects/stringobject.c#l72), and that's only for strings with 1 characters.

Comment: The array of single-character string objects optimizes string subscription and iteration. It gets bypassed, however, if you use an escape such as `'\n'` or `'\x00'`, as opposed to `chr(10)` and `chr(0)`, so those will be new objects. Except, coming back to code objects, the name characters will be interned in the `interned` `dict`. Also, a bug in codeobject.c `all_name_chars` causes `'\x00'` to be interned as well.

Comment: @eryksun interesting, please feel free to edit the answer :)