# Change id of copied value from a list

Tags: python, copy

I've copied one element of a list but the id is still the same.

```
t=['bancorp', 'bancorp','bancorp ba','bancorp ali', 'gas eu', 'gas', 'karl', 'bancorp','bancorp america','uni','gas for','gas tr']

n=t[2]

id(n)
124661664

id(t[2])
124661664
```

I´ve tried this but the ID is still the same:

```
n=cp.deepcopy(t[2])
```

How Can I copy the value but with different ID?

**EDIT:**

When I slice:`n=t[2:3][0]`. The id is different.

But when I slice: `n=t[0:1][0]`. The ID is the same. Why did it happen?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so it's never useful to copy them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want an independent copy of the element of a list, so the ID should be different. Check my edit.

Comment: @CreamStat an "independent copy" isn't relevant here, because strings are immutable; you cannot change them in-place.

Comment: @Creamstat but why? There is no advantage to having two copies of the same string.

Comment: It makes as much sense as wanting several copies of the number 2.

Answer (score 3):

In python, smaller strings are [`interned`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182261/python-id-behavior-in-the-interpreter). This allows for efficient memory use since strings are immutable. In short, for small identical strings you will get the same `id` value.

As to why `t[2:3][0]` was not interned, and `t[0:1][0]` was, it looks like Cython does not intern strings with whitespace.

Comment: So, Is there no way I can get an independent copy of the first value f my list?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really determined to create a separate copy of a string, you could do:

```
>>> s = 'foo'
>>> t = ''.join(s)
>>> s
'foo'
>>> t
'foo'
>>> id(s) == id(t)
False
```

However, as strings are immutable (i.e. can't be changed in-place) you don't really get any benefit from this. For example:

```
>>> a = list('foo')
>>> a
['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> b = a[:] # only a shallow copy
>>> id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
True # share the same object
>>> a[0] += 'l' # 'modify' one of them
>>> a
['fl', 'o', 'o'] # changes a
>>> b
['f', 'o', 'o'] # doesn't change b
```

Answer (score -1):

Craete a empty list and try to copy

```
t=['bancorp', 'bancorp','bancorp ba','bancorp ali', 'gas eu', 'gas', 'karl', 'bancorp','bancorp america','uni','gas for','gas tr']
n = []
n = t[2:3]

print id(n)

print id(t[2])
```

Comment: Not very useful - here `n` is an empty list, which (although it does not have the same id as `t[2]`) isn't what the OP wants. `t[2:3]` would give a list with the single element `t[2]`, but `id(t[2:3][0]) == id(t[2])`.

Comment: Just `print n` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Why it doesn't work when n=t[0:1][0] ? In that case, the ID is still the same!

Comment: @MONTYHS `id(n) != id(t[2])` simply because `['bancorp ba'] != 'bancorp ba'` Note that `id(n[0]) == id(t[2])`.