# How can I copy a Python string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I do this:

```
a = 'hello'
```

And now I just want an independent copy of `a`:

```
import copy

b = str(a)
c = a[:]
d = a + ''
e = copy.copy(a)

map( id, [ a,b,c,d,e ] )
```

Out[3]:

```
[4365576160, 4365576160, 4365576160, 4365576160, 4365576160]
```

Why do they all have the same memory address and how can I get a copy of `a`?

Comment: To get answer different from Martijin's (which is entirely correct, though doesn't necessarily answer question as stated) you might want to provide more detail/use case to show **why** you want it copied.

Comment: As @elemo implies, this might be an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Comment: I was interested in estimating the memory usage of a nested dictionary of the form `d[ 'hello' ] = e`, where `e[ 'hi' ] = 'again'`. To generate such a nested dictionary, I generated a single `e` dictionary  and copied it multiple times. I noticed that the memory consumption was very low, which led to my question here. Now I understand that no string copies were created, hence the low memory consumption.

Comment: If you want `b` to be a modified version of `a` without modifying `a`, just let `b` be the result of whatever operation. e.g. `b = a[2:-1]` sets `b` to `'ll'` and `a` remains '`hello'`.

Comment: Ollie is correct. This is because str is an immutable type. Due to python's use of singletons (and probably other internal optimizations), You won't see the memory expand like you expect when copying the e dictionary.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You don't *need* to copy a Python string. They are immutable, and the `copy` module always returns the original in such cases, as do `str()`, the whole string slice, and concatenating with an empty string.

Moreover, your `'hello'` string is *interned* ([certain strings are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string/24245514#24245514)). Python deliberately tries to keep just the one copy, as that makes dictionary lookups faster.

One way you could work around this is to actually create a new string, then slice that string back to the original content:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> b = (a + '.')[:-1]
>>> id(a), id(b)
(4435312528, 4435312432)
```

But all you are doing now is waste memory. It is not as if you can mutate these string objects in any way, after all.

If all you wanted to know is how much memory a Python object requires, use [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof); it gives you the memory footprint of any Python object.

For containers this does **not** include the contents; you'd have to recurse into each container to calculate a total memory size:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
42
>>> b = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
280
>>> sys.getsizeof(b) + sum(sys.getsizeof(k) + sys.getsizeof(v) for k, v in b.items())
360
```

You can then choose to use `id()` tracking to take an actual memory footprint or to estimate a maximum footprint if objects were not cached and reused.

Comment: There's more than only one way to create a new string object, such as `b = ''.join(a)`.

Comment: @martineau: sure, I really meant to say 'one way'.

Comment: Emphasis on "You don't need to copy a Python string". There's a reason why those operations simply return the same string.

Comment: In this case, though, the OP is attempting to waste memory. Since he wants to know how much memory will be used by a certain quantity of strings, that is the actual goal. Obviously he could generate unique strings, but that's just unnecessary work as a workaround.

Comment: +1 for "casually" using an example that would output [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Comment: To everyone who is so unquestionably certain that one *never* has a need to copy a string: What if am trying to ensure that ('EUR', ''.join('EUR')) and ('EUR', 'EUR') to serialize to the exact same stream of bytes given a serialization format that will preserve identity (e.g. for arg sake pickle.dumps)? I can either 1. intern all possible strings 2. explicitly make a copy of all strings before serializing. It's reasonable in some use cases to want to do #2 - but "those who know better" have made this pretty difficult to do.

Comment: @PaulHollingsworth: are we talking about the *optimisation* strategy where `pickle` sometimes uses object identity to minimize data transfer sizes? That's an implementation detail; don't rely on implementation details!

Answer (score 23):

I'm just starting some string manipulations and found this question.  I was probably trying to do something like the OP, "usual me".  The previous answers did not clear up my confusion, but after thinking a little about it I finally "got it".

As long as `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` have the same value, they reference to the same place.  Memory is saved.  As soon as the variable start to have different values, they get start to have different references.  My learning experience came from this code:

```
import copy
a = 'hello'
b = str(a)
c = a[:]
d = a + ''
e = copy.copy(a)

print map( id, [ a,b,c,d,e ] )

print a, b, c, d, e

e = a + 'something'
a = 'goodbye'
print map( id, [ a,b,c,d,e ] )
print a, b, c, d, e
```

The printed output is:

```
[4538504992, 4538504992, 4538504992, 4538504992, 4538504992]

hello hello hello hello hello

[6113502048, 4538504992, 4538504992, 4538504992, 5570935808]

goodbye hello hello hello hello something
```

Comment: More details for the behavior are described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 18):

You can copy a string in python via string formatting :

```
>>> a = 'foo'  
>>> b = '%s' % a  
>>> id(a), id(b)  
(140595444686784, 140595444726400)
```

Comment: Not true in Python 3.6.5. id(a) and id(b) are identical. The results are no different even when I used the modern version of format, viz., `b = '{:s}'.format(a)`

Answer (score 8):

To put it a different way "id()" is not what you care about. You want to know if the variable name can be modified without harming the source variable name.

```
>>> a = 'hello'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> b = a[:]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>>> c = a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> b += ' world'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> c += ', bye'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
'hello'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
'hello world'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
'hello, bye'
```

If you're used to C, then these are like pointer variables except you can't de-reference them to modify what they point at, but id() will tell you where they currently point.

The problem for python programmers comes when you consider deeper structures like lists or dicts:

```
>>> o={'a': 10}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> x=o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> y=o.copy()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> x['a'] = 20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> y['a'] = 30                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
{'a': 20}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
{'a': 20}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
{'a': 30}
```

Here o and x refer to the same dict o['a'] and x['a'], and that dict is "mutable" in the sense that you can change the value for key 'a'. That's why "y" needs to be a copy and y['a'] can refer to something else.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, using this simple trick :

```
a = "Python"
b = a[ : : -1 ][ : : -1 ]
print( "a =" , a )
print( "b =" , b )
a == b  # True
id( a ) == id( b ) # False
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have already explained, there's rarely an actual need for this, but nevertheless, here you go:
(works on Python 3, but there's probably something similar for Python 2)

```py
import ctypes

copy          = ctypes.pythonapi._PyUnicode_Copy
copy.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
copy.restype  = ctypes.py_object

s1 = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
s2 = copy(s1)

id(s1) == id(s2) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have just solved this with string slicing.

```
a="words"
b=a[:int(len(a)/2)]+a[int(len(a)/2):]
b
'words'
id(a),id(b)
(1492873997808, 1492902431216)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying a string can be done two ways either copy the location a = "a" b = a or you can clone which means b wont get affected when a is changed which is done by a = 'a' b = a[:]