# Simplest way to defeat string interning in Python

Tags: python, string-interning

I have a case where I would like to defeat string interning.

Let's say the string I have is `"foo bar"`.

I know of a few hacky/not obvious ways to defeat interning a string.  All involve computing the expression at runtime.

```py
In [1]: my_str = "foo bar"
In [2]: my_new_str1 = " ".join(["foo", "bar"])
In [3]: my_new_str2 = "foo bar "[:-1]
In [4]: my_new_str3 = "foo " + "bar"

In [5]: id(my_str)
Out[5]: 4483028144

In [6]: id(my_new_str1)
Out[6]: 4483030192

In [7]: id(my_new_str2)
Out[7]: 4484125872

In [8]: id(my_new_str3)
Out[8]: 4484052336
```

There is a built-in function [`sys.intern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern), which interns a string.  I am looking to do the exact opposite, *not* intern something in a simple/descriptive way.

Is there anything out there that can defeat string interning in a "clean" way?

Comment: Please say why?

Comment: Why would you need to avoid string interning? strings are immutable which  means once you have string, no one can change it

Comment: Long story short, I want `is` checks to return `False`.  So if I said `spam = "hi"` and `ham = "hi"`, I want `spam is ham` to return `False`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664581) has the most direct low level copy.

Comment: One reason you might want this would be if you want to tell the difference between a default value and an equivalent value that was passed in. For instance, using the argparse module, you can set a default argument value there is no direct way to determine if the value came from the default or was specified explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also subclass `str`.

```
>>> class UninternedStr(str):
...   pass
... 
>>> s = UninternedStr('a string')
>>> s1 = UninternedStr('a string')
>>> s is s1
False
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose put a function around join:

```
def new_str(s):
    return ''.join(s)

>>> s='a string'

>>> s1=new_str(s)

>>> id(s)
4568404208

>>> id(s1)
4569455664

>>> s is s1
False
```

But I think this is silly...

Comment: Yes thank you @dawg for the answer.  In the OP, I already included `.join` as one method.  I was wondering if there's a more descriptive/meaningful way.  I would prefer not to add a utility function `new_str` to my client code, even though it's not many lines of code

Comment: *Descriptive* and *meaningful* are in the eye of the beholder. What is descriptive and meaningful to you?