# Why is the [:] included in `.removeprefix()` definition?

Tags: python, string

In [PEP-616](https://peps.python.org/pep-0616/), the specification for `removeprefix()` includes this code block:

```
def removeprefix(self: str, prefix: str, /) -> str:
    if self.startswith(prefix):
        return self[len(prefix):]
    else:
        return self[:]
```

Why does the last line say `return self[:]`, instead of just `return self`?

Comment: It is a common, but outdated idiom for copying a sequence. The string class lacks a copy method, since it isn't ordinarily necessary to copy a string; and this [shouldn't work anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804453/how-can-i-copy-a-python-string). Or is the question "why does the specification say to copy the string?"?

Comment: Probably just for symmetry with the `if` clause, but please understand, that is not the actual implementation.

Comment: ... in order to return a *new* string, `self` does not change.

Comment: No, that's certainly it, which makes sense! It's a simpler idiom to copy the string as the return value. Thanks!

Comment: @MauriceMeyer but it *doesn't actually return a new string*.

Comment: @PhilipMassey it doesn't actually copy the string. This is easy to verify, `s = 'foo'; print(s is s.removeprefix('bar'))`.

Comment: Ah, no, wait; I noticed a subtlety.

Comment: Here's the actual implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/046cbc2080360b0b0bbe6ea7554045a6bbbd94bd/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11933 I am not sure what [`unicode_result_unchanged`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/046cbc2080360b0b0bbe6ea7554045a6bbbd94bd/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L609) is doing.... but there's a lot of subtleties going on underneath the hood for unicode objects/

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga perhaps for you it's easy to verify :) thanks for the reminder to update Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[:]` is an [old idiom for copying sequences](/questions/2612802/). Nowadays, we use the idiomatic `.copy` for lists; there isn't normally a good reason to copy strings, since they are supposed to be immutable, so the `str` class doesn't provide such a method. Furthermore, due to string interning, `[:]` [may well return the same instance anyway](/questions/24804453).

So, why include it in code like this?

Because `str` can be subclassed. The clue is in the subsequent text:

> When the arguments are instances of `str` subclasses, the methods should behave as though those arguments were first coerced to base `str` objects, and the return value should always be a base `str`.

Suppose we had a user-defined subclass:

```
class MyString(str):
    ...
```

Notice what happens when we slice an instance to copy it:

```
>>> type(MyString('xyz')[:])
<class 'str'>
```

In the example implementation, therefore, the `[:]` ensures that an instance of the base `str` type will be returned, conforming to the text specification.

Comment: Who is the "we" in "we use the idiomatic .copy for lists"? Most people seem to use [:], I rarely ever see people use .copy

Comment: The same "we" who used 3.x before being absolutely forced into it, I guess.