# How to determine an ID on Python?

Tags: python

How to determine an ID on Python?

I heard that the same strings have the same IDs like below:

```
>>>list1=[1,2,'aaa','bbb']
>>>list2=[3,4,'aaa','bbb']
>>>id(list1[2])
12345
>>>id(list2[2])
12345
```

but the following case does not hold the rule:

```
>>>list1=[1,2,'Hello World','bbb']
>>>list2=[3,4,'Hello World','bbb']
>>>id(list1[2])
12345
>>>id(list2[2])
12367
```

How are they different from each other?

### Added

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 'aaa', 'bbb']
>>> list2 = [2, 3, 'aaa', 'bbb']
>>> id(list1[2])
4511557072
>>> id(list2[2])
4511557072
>>> list3 = [1, 2, 'Hello World', 'bbb']
>>> list4 = [2, 3, 'Hello World', 'bbb']
>>> id(list3[2])
4511542272
>>> id(list4[2])
4511542368
```

Comment: This almost never matters with immutable objects like strings. What do you need the strings' IDs for?

Comment: i just wonder what makes the different :)

Comment: Also, when posting interpreter session transcripts, please copy-paste from an actual interpreter session rather than making up output. Made-up output is frequently wrong in crucial ways.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example. As @Marcin stated, your second snippet does not execute.

Comment: You might have the wrong concept about `id` there. It points to a memory location at which the String is stored. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string

Comment: @user2357112 , i'm sorry about that, i will chage

Comment: @Calon , thank you for answer. i will see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason is that in your second example you use `id(lst2[2])` instead of `id(list2[2])`. But in general I think, its up to python's interpreter to decide whether string objects containing the same string are actually the same string objects or not.

In addition this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings) has a bit of discussion and answers related to this question.

Comment: nope this is not the answer.

Comment: @A.J. I updated the answer. But if my answer is not correct, that which one is the correct one?

Comment: Now that is the question :)

Comment: @A.J. So please feel to provide the correct answer.

Comment: The link is worth the upvote. Indeed, it's about autointerning of short strings.

Answer (score -2):

Your assumption of same string having the same id is right.

Could you give more details about your code? This is what I have got:

```
>>> list2=[3,4,'aaa','bbb']
>>> list1=[1,2,'aaa','bbb']
>>> list2=[3,4,'aaa','bbb']
>>> id(list1[2])
4449536920
>>> id(list2[2])
4449536920
```

Comment: 'aaa' case returns same IDs. but 'Hello world' case does not.

Comment: It has a space. Check it in python interpreter. id(" ") is a constant through out. But id("  ") (two spaces) changes