# When can one use the `is` operator in Python to determine if two objects are the same object as opposed to just having the same value?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, comparison, equality

I am not asking when to use `==` vs `is` in Python which is a question that has been asked and answered many times before.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python), `==` checks if two arguments have the same value, and `is` checks if the they refer to the same object.

So if one creates two objects with the same value,

```
>>> fruit_name = 'Apple'
>>> company_name = 'Apple'
```

one would expect `==` to return `True` and `is` to return `False`. However this is what actually happens:

```
>>> fruit_name == company_name # True expected since they have the same value
True
>>> fruit_name is company_name 
True
```

Why is Python considering `fruit_name` and `company_name` to be the same object as opposed to different objects with the same value? And when can one rely on `is` to return True if and only if the arguments are intentionally set to be the same object by the programmer?

Comment: rely on `is` only for singletons (`None` for instance). Not for strings or integers, that's for sure.

Comment: You got lucky. Sometimes the interpreter reuses the same value across multiple variables. This is true mostly for immutable types.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings

Comment: Also see [About the changing id of an immutable string](//stackoverflow.com/q/24245324)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am not asking when to use `is` vs `==` which I already acknowledged as previously answered so this question is not an exact duplicate of the first question you linked to. The 2nd question you linked to is similar but is far more complicated and hard to follow.

Comment: who can find a better duplicate than the 2 above? oh Martjin already added that one.

Comment: I found this answer helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504848/5191836

Comment: ok, linked to the Q