# How to create the str "1" at two different memory locations?

Tags: python, caching, implementation, cpython, string-interning

We are able to defeat the small integer intern in this way (a calculation allows us to avoid the caching layer):

```
>>> n = 674039
>>> one1 = 1
>>> one2 = (n ** 9 + 1) % (n ** 9)
>>> one1 == one2
True
>>> one1 is one2
False
```

How can you defeat the small string intern, i.e. to see the following result:

```
>>> one1 = "1"
>>> one2 = <???>
>>> type(one2) is str and one1 == one2
True
>>> one1 is one2
False
```

[`sys.intern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern) mentions that "*Interned strings are not immortal*", but there's no context about how a string could kicked out of the intern, or how you can create a `str` instance avoiding the caching layer.

<sub>*Since interning is CPython implementation detail, answers relying on undocumented implementation details are ok/expected.*</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758234/4001592 ?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123925/when-does-python-allocate-new-memory-for-identical-strings

Comment: For sizes >= 2 it is trivial `"12" is "123"[0:2]` yield False. However,  length 1 seems to be special...

Comment: That is the line part that needs to be avoided for size==1: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L5153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode consisting of only one character (with value smaller than 128 or more precisely from `latin1`) is the most complicated case, because those strings aren't really [interned](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a65c86889e208dddb26a7ebe7840c24edbcca775/Include/internal/pycore_interp.h#L82) but (more similar to the integer pool or identically to the behavior for `bytes`) are created at the start and [are stored in an array](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a65c86889e208dddb26a7ebe7840c24edbcca775/Include/internal/pycore_interp.h#L71) as long as the interpreter is alive:

```c
truct _Py_unicode_state {
    ...
    /* Single character Unicode strings in the Latin-1 range are being
       shared as well. */
    PyObject *latin1[256];
    ...
    /* This dictionary holds all interned unicode strings...
    */
    PyObject *interned;
    ...
};
```

So every time a length 1 unicode is created, the character value gets looked up if it is in the `latin1`-array. E.g. in  [`unicode_decode_utf8`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a65c86889e208dddb26a7ebe7840c24edbcca775/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L5142):

```
/* ASCII is equivalent to the first 128 ordinals in Unicode. */
    if (size == 1 && (unsigned char)s[0] < 128) {
        if (consumed) {
            *consumed = 1;
        }
        return get_latin1_char((unsigned char)s[0]);
    }
```

One could even argue, if there is a way to circumvent this in the interpreter - we speak about a (performance-) bug.

A possibility is to populate the unicode-data by ourselves using C-API. I use `Cython` for the proof of concept, but also `ctypes` could be used to the same effect:

```py
%%cython
cdef extern from *:
    """
    PyObject* create_new_unicode(char *ch) 
    {
       PyUnicodeObject *ob = (PyUnicodeObject *)PyUnicode_New(1, 127);
       Py_UCS1 *data = PyUnicode_1BYTE_DATA(ob);
       data[0]=ch[0]; //fill data without using the unicode_decode_utf8
       return (PyObject*)ob;
    }
    """
    object create_new_unicode(char *ch)
    
def gen1():
    return create_new_unicode(b"1")
```

Noteworthy details:

- `PyUnicode_New` would not look up in `latin1`, because the characters aren't set yet.
- For simplicity, the above works only for ASCII characters - thus we pass `127` as `maxchar` to `PyUnicode_New`. As result, we can interpret data via `PyUnicode_1BYTE_DATA` which makes it easy to manipulate it without much ado manually.

And now:

```py
a,b=gen1(), gen1()
a is b, a == b
# yields (False, True)
```

as wanted.

---

Here is a similar idea, but implemented with `ctypes`:

```
from ctypes import POINTER, py_object, c_ssize_t, byref, pythonapi
PyUnicode_New = pythonapi.PyUnicode_New
PyUnicode_New.argtypes = (c_ssize_t, c_ssize_t)
PyUnicode_New.restype = py_object
PyUnicode_CopyCharacters = pythonapi._PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters
PyUnicode_CopyCharacters.argtypes = (py_object, c_ssize_t, py_object, c_ssize_t, c_ssize_t)
PyUnicode_CopyCharacters.restype = c_ssize_t

def clone(orig):
    cloned = PyUnicode_New(1,127)
    PyUnicode_CopyCharacters(cloned, 0, orig, 0, 1)
    return cloned
```

Noteworthy details:

- It is not possible to use `PyUnicode_1BYTE_DATA` with ctypes, because it is a macro. An alternative would be to calculate the offset to `data`-member and directly access this memory (but it depends on the platform and doesn't feel very portable)
- As work-around, `PyUnicode_CopyCharacters` is used (there are probably also other possibilities to achieve the same), which is more abstract and portable than directly calculating/accessing the memory.
- Actually, `_PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters` is used, because `PyUnicode_CopyCharacters` would check, that the target-unicode has multiple references and throw. `_PyUnicode_FastCopyCharacters` doesn't perform those checks and does as asked.

And now:

```py
a="1"
b=clone(a)
a is b, a==b
# yields (False, True)
```

---

For strings longer than 1 character, it is a lot easier to avoid interning, e.g.:

```py
a="12"
b="123"[0:2]
a is b, a == b
#yields (False, True)
```