# Is this a memory leak? (python + numpy)

Tags: python, memory-leaks, numpy

The following code fills all my memory:

```
from sys import getsizeof
import numpy

# from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117379/272471
def getSize(array):
    return getsizeof(array) + len(array) * getsizeof(array[0])


class test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def t(self):
        temp = numpy.zeros([200,100,100])
        A = numpy.zeros([200], dtype = numpy.float64)
        for i in range(200):
            A[i] = numpy.sum( temp[i].diagonal() ) 
        return A

a = test()
memory_usage("before")
c = [a.t() for i in range(100)]
del a
memory_usage("After")
print("Size of c:", float(getSize(c))/1000.0)
```

The output is:

```
('>', 'before', 'memory:', 20588, 'KiB  ')
('>', 'After', 'memory:', 1583456, 'KiB  ')
('Size of c:', 8.92)
```

Why am I using ~1.5 GB of memory if c is ~ 9 KiB? Is this a memory leak? (Thanks)

The `memory_usage` function was posted on SO and is reported here for clarity:

```
def memory_usage(text = ''):
    """Memory usage of the current process in kilobytes."""
    status = None
    result = {'peak': 0, 'rss': 0}
    try:
        # This will only work on systems with a /proc file system
        # (like Linux).
        status = open('/proc/self/status')
        for line in status:
            parts = line.split()
            key = parts[0][2:-1].lower()
            if key in result:
                result[key] = int(parts[1])
    finally:
        if status is not None:
            status.close()
    print('>', text, 'memory:', result['rss'], 'KiB  ')
    return result['rss']
```

Comment: Replace `float(getsizeof(c))/1000.0)` with `float(getSize(c))/1000.0)` and you should get a better value.

Comment: Thanks glglgl, I actually copied the wrong version of my sample code. Corrected.

Comment: what happens if you put in a del temp just before the return statement in t()?

Comment: Doesn't work. As I wrote, the problem comes from a memory leak in the diagonal function of numpy v. 1.7.0. Fixed in v 1.7.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of `diagonal()` failed to decrement a reference counter.  This issue had been previously fixed, but [the change](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/80b3a3401382cb3f14c5b76dd90d9f932f50ad15) didn't make it into 1.7.0.

Upgrading to 1.7.1 solves the problem! The [release notes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.7.1-notes.html) contain various useful identifiers, notably [issue 2969](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2969).

The solution was provided by Sebastian Berg and Charles Harris on the [NumPy mailing list](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/numpy-discussion@python.org/thread/MH3XN6U53N4VGYVLE7PS5E337S4HSGXJ/).

Comment: Would be helpful to link to documentation of what was actually fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Python allocs memory from the OS if it needs some.

If it doesn't need it any longer, it may or may not return it again.

But if it doesn't return it, the memory will be reused on subsequent allocations. You should check that; but supposedly the memory consumption won't increase even more.

About your estimations of memory consumption: As azorius already wrote, your `temp` array consumes 16 MB, while your `A` array consumes about 200 * 8 = 1600 bytes (+ 40 for internal reasons). If you take 100 of them, you are at 164000 bytes (plus some for the list).

Besides that, I have no explanation for the memory consumption you have.

Comment: That's clear, thanks. Nonetheless if I increase the number of times I call `a.t()` to 200 my process gets killed by the kernel. Why is this happening? I should have 2*9 = 18 KiB of memory usage, isn't it?

Comment: @Pie86 check my post, 200 numpy matrixes of that size takes atleast 3 GB space, you do not delete the returned matrixes, only the tiny little class that creates them.

Comment: @azorius that's right, but I keep only the small returned matrix. The problem, as you suggested, is the big temporary matrix `temp` that is not deleted together with the class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sys.getsizeof returns what you expect

your numpy vector A is 64 bit (8 bytes) - so it takes up (at least)

```
8 * 200 * 100 * 100 * 100 / (2.0**30) = 1.5625 GB
```

so at minimum you should use 1.5 GB on the 100 arrays, the last few hundred mg are all the integers used for indexing the large numpy data and the 100 objects

It seems that sys.getsizeof always returns 80 no matter how large a numpy array is:

```
sys.getsizeof(np.zeros([200,1000,100])) # return 80
sys.getsizeof(np.zeros([20,100,10])) # return 80
```

In your code you delete a which is a tiny factory object who's t method return huge numpy arrays, you store these huge arrays in a list called c.
try to delete c, then you should regain most of your RAM

Comment: `8 * 200 * 100 * 100 = 16000000 B = 15625 kiB = 15.2587890625 MiB`, three orders of magnitude smaller than you anticipated. But that counts for one A only, we have 100 of them. An older system might get into trouble with these sizes...

Comment: @glglgl yes but 15 MB * 100 = 1.5GB... I was a little to trigger happy with my post as I always post a quick post and then edit out ALL the errors, thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @glglgl he thinks he has a memmory leak becuse he is loosing 1.6 GB, but even though he deletes a, his class returns 100 numpy matrixes (that he does not delete) so they are still in memory

Comment: Ok, but temp should be removed (deallocated). I don't want to store it as the name suggests. And A is much smaller, it's just 200 numpy.float64 times 100 iterations!

8 * 200 * 100 = 160000 is the size that I want to use.

Comment: You and glglgl are absolutely right, my bad :)... if I should try to guess what is going on is is the folloing: python have 3 lairs of buckets inside each other where it allocate memory, and it can only 'give back a chunk of memory' to the os if the outer bucket is completely empty... But other than that I am out of idear, a hack solution would be to generate the temp in the __init__ and then resycle it such that you do not generate 100 of them if python is not able to succesfully dealocate them